# Spark RDD remove records with multiple keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark RDD that looks like this:

```
[(1, ...),
(1, ...),
(2, ...),
(3, ...)]
```

And I am trying to remove the records that have duplicate keys, in this case, I want to exclude all the records that have key '1'. And the ultimate output I want should look like

```
[(2, ...),
(3, ...)]
```

What I have tried so far, it worked but my gut says there should be a better solution:

```
>> a = sc.parallelize([(1,[1,1]), (1,[1,1]), (2,[1,1]), (3,[1,1])])
>> print a.groupByKey() \
    .filter(lambda x: len(x[1])==1 ) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])[0] )).collect()
[(2, [1, 1]), (3, [1, 1])]
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work so it can be improved? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also, if you could take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/33157978/1560062 If you don't find answer useful I'll just delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other options:

1. `subtractByKey` - this requires shuffling so total cost can be similar to `groupByKey`. Optionally you can partition input `RDD` and with `preservesPartitioning` set to `True`:

   ```
   from operator import add

   counts = (a.keys()
       .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
       .reduceByKey(add))

   duplicates = (counts
       .filter(lambda x:  x[1] >  1)
       .map(lambda x: (x[0], None)))

   a.subtractByKey(duplicates)
   ```
2. Broadcast variable:

   - positive filter - if you expect a large number of duplicates

     ```
     non_duplicated = sc.broadcast(set(
         counts.filter(lambda x: x[1] == 1).keys().collect()
     ))

     a.filter(lambda x: x[0] in non_duplicated.value)
     ```
   - negative filter - if expected a low number of duplicates

     ```
     duplicated = sc.broadcast(set(
         counts.filter(lambda x: x[1] > 1).keys().collect()
     ))

     a.filter(lambda x: x[0] not in duplicated.value)
     ```