# Display URL Image Using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that contains a column with URL links, I want each of the images displayed.

I tried the following solution for local files but it didn't work for URL links. 
[Spark using PySpark read images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138129/spark-using-pyspark-read-images)

If anyone knows how to accomplish this for a pyspark dataframe using an URL link, please do share.

Example of url jpg: 
https://steemitimages.com/DQmWSoXZPHH2XEuVRUbPqiPLf6niA2xfvFXYZ2FYPYhMQ4X/1%20(3).jpg

Comment: Hi loading image only work for local path or hdfs like path. You can only download this image to local disk then load it .

Answer (score 1):

Loading image only work for local path or hdfs like path. 
You can only download this image to local disk then load it .

```py
import urllib.request

# path to your image source directory
sample_img_dir = /tmp/images

urllib.request.urlretrieve(' https://steemitimages.com/DQmWSoXZPHH2XEuVRUbPqiPLf6niA2xfvFXYZ2FYPYhMQ4X/1%20(3).jpg', sample_img_dir+'/image1.jpg')


# Read image data using new image scheme
image_df = spark.read.format("image")\
           .option("dropInvalid", true)\
           .load(sample_img_dir)


image_df.select("image.origin", "image.width", "image.height").show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------+-----+------+
|origin                                     |width|height|
+-------------------------------------------+-----+------+
|file:///tmp/images/image1.jpg              |300  |311   |
|file:///tmp/images/image2.jpg              |199  |313   |
|file:///tmp/images/image3.jpg              |300  |200   |
|file:///tmp/images/image4.jpg              |300  |296   |
+-------------------------------------------+-----+------+
```

Reference:

- [Introducing Built-in Image Data Source in Apache Spark 2.4](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/12/10/introducing-built-in-image-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html)