# OpenCV read images from pyspark and pass to a Keras model

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, opencv, pyspark

This is a follow-up question to the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274419/554481). I'm using PySpark 2.4.4. I have a bunch of images (some .png some .jpeg) stored on Google Cloud Storage (GCS) that I need to pass to a Tensorflow model. I'm getting my images like this.

```
images = spark.read.format("image").option("dropInvalid", False).load("gs://my-bucket/my_image.jpg")
images = images.collect()
image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(images[0].image.data, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Based on the OpenCV documentation I've read, it seems like OpenCV isn't able to understand my data format. I know this because `cv2.imdecode(...)` returns `None`. The official Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-datasource#image-data-source) explicitly mentions compatibility with OpenCV, so I know it's possible.

Eventually I want to be able to do this.

```
prediction = model.predict(np.array([image]))[0]
```

Outside of Spark, if I get my image not from GCS but from an http endpoint, all I have to do is this, which works.

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url)
image = resp.read()
prediction = model.predict(np.array([image]))[0]
```

To get a better sense of what the model is looking for, this is what the data should look like before it's passed into the `np.array([...])` part.

```
print(resp.read())
>>> b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\ ...'
```

I can confirm that the images aren't corrupted when they're on GCS. When I download the same image from GCS to my laptop, and then read it like this, I get a similarly looking format. The model is also able to consume the image this way. I've also visually inspected the downloaded GCS image, and it looks fine.

```
with open("./my_image.jpeg", "rb") as image:
    print(image.read())
>>> b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\ ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I was able to achieve by converting PIL images to cv2 image.

**Spark loading :**

```html
images = sc.binaryFiles('/tmp/images/*', 10)
df = images.map(lambda img: extract_line_coords(img)).toDF()
df.show(5, False)
```

**Function**

```html
def extract_line_coords(binary_images):
    name, img = binary_images
    pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img)).convert('RGB') 
    cv2_image = numpy.array(pil_image) 
    cv2_image = cv2_image[:, :, ::-1].copy() 
    gray     = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ...
    ...
```

Reference : [Convert image from PIL to openCV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format)